# How to change color of matplotlib (zoom) crosshair?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Almost all of the images, that I am ploting are gray. Therefore I have problems while finding the "crosshair" in the plots. Please see the attached image.
How can I change the color of the crosshair?

I am just executing the commands

```
self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
imshow(image)
```

[image]

Edit:
I am talking about the crosshair after pressing the "zoom" button in the matplotlib toolbar:
[image]

Comment: How is this cursor generated in your code? Rather important to answer your question.

Comment: @Mr.T it is the standard cursor of a matplotlib plot window. I didn't generate it exolicitly. In the end I am just executing the commands 'self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)', 'self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)' and later on 'imshow(image)' for showing the image.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. This cursor does not appear in my matplotlib version just because I display an image. Matplotlib has [cursor examples with color attributes](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/widgets/cursor.html), though.

Comment: @Mr.T Ah sorry - I do not have created a cursor by myself, but I am talking about the crosshair of the "zoom" feature of the matplotlib toolbar. I have missed this point. After pressing the zoom button, the crosshair is visible in the gray image in a gray color as you can see here: https://imgur.com/p80Kj6t
I would like to change this crosshair color to be better visible.

Comment: It depends on your system.

Comment: @Lescurel what does it mean, that it depends on the system. Anyways one should be able to change the color somehow, right?

Comment: The cursor is managed by your OS, not by matplotlib. You can try to change it to a contrast friendly version in the accessibility settings.

Comment: Switching to high contrast mode in Windows 10 does also not change the cursor color or contrast. Any other ideas?